# Why tornado request timeout is caped to 30s

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I'm making http post request with this function:

```
    client = AsyncHTTPClient() 
    kwargs["method"] = "POST" 
    kwargs["validate_cert"] = False 
    kwargs["headers"] = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 
    kwargs["request_timeout"] = 45.0 
    kwargs["connect_timeout"] = 60.0 
        
    print(args) 
    print(kwargs) 
    r = await client.fetch(*args, **kwargs) 
    return r
```

But, the request timeout seems to be caped to 30s:

- for request_timeout =< 30, I've got `http error: 599 Stream closed` after the request_timeout duration
- for request_timeout > 30, like here = 45, the time is raised always at 30 seconds.

Is there a high limit on request_timeout ? Can we bypass it?

Thanks